# Approximating derivative of numerical solution (using ode45) within event function

Tags: matlab

The issue I have is having to compute the derivative (in real time) of the solution produced by `ode45` within the events function.

Some pseudo-code to explain what I'm mean is,

```
function dx = myfunc(t,x,xevent,ie)
persistent xs
persistent dx2
% xevent is the solution at the event
if isempty(dx2) == 1
    dx2 = 0;
end
k = sign(dx2*x(1));
if ie(end) == 1
    xs = xevent
elseif ie(end) == 2
    xs = xevent
end
dx(1) = x(2);
dx(2) = function of k,x(1),x(2), and xs;
dx2 = dx(2);
end
```

and

```
function [value,isterminal,direction] = myeventfcn(t,x)
if dx(2)*x(1)>=0
    position = [dx(2)*x(1); dx(2)*x(1)];
    isterminal = [1; 1];
    direction = [1 ; -1 ];
elseif dx(2)x(1)<0
    position = [dx(2)*x(1); dx(2)*x(1)];
    isterminal = [1; 1];
    direction = [-1 ; 1 ];
end
```

I know that if I didn't need to use the solution at the event within `myfunc` I could just compute `dx=myfunc(t,x)` within my event function and use `dx(2)`, yet since `xevent` is used within `myfunc` I can't input `xevent`.

I know there is a way of inputting constant parameters within the event function, but since it's the solution at the event location, which also changes, I'm not sure how to go about doing that.

My work around to this is to approximate `dx(2)` using the solution `x`. What I wanted to know is if it will be satisfactory to just use a finite difference approximation here, using a small fixed step size relative to the step size `od45` takes, which is a variable step size.

**EDIT:** I went ahead and updated my code to reflect what `myfunc` and `myeventfcn` would look like. As a note, the reason I have `myeventfcn` split by the `if` statement is to know what the direction the event is crossed, since it will update within `myfunc`.

Also, I need to use `dx(2)` of the previous successful time step and so that's why I have `dx2` defined as a persistent variable. I believe having `k=sign(dx(2)*x(1))` is okay to do, since my event depends on `dx(2)*x(1)`, and so I won't be introducing any new discontinuities with the `sign` function.

Comment: I think it might be clearer to give an abstracted version of what you are actually trying to do; we don't really care what your ODE is but we do care what the events roughly look like and what you need to do when they occur.

Comment: @Ian I went ahead and updated my problem to show more precisely what `myfunc` and `myeventfcn` would look like. Thank you for looking this over.